# create norway-citizens tag as alias or norwegian-citizens tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

idk it seems like it's something people could type in accidentally enough. I'd create the synonym myself but lack the rep points to do so!

Answer (score 3):

Done. [norwegian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norwegian-citizens) is the master tag, [norway-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norway-citizens) is its synonym.